# How to open a JQ dialogue box on submit event?

Tags: jquery

I have a search field. I want to show the results in a dialogue box. The search field doesn't have any button. So, what event i should call to open the dialogue box after pressing enter.

Any suggestions!

**Update**

For the whole project, its all HTML, JavaScript & Jquery in client side, Java is in back.
What i want to know is, under which event i have to put the dialogue box generation codes and data manipulation codes.

Comment: What server side technology do you use?

Comment: @shaahin: Its java, and the result coming back from server with DWR!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). It allows you make a normal form into an AJAX form, posting back without reloading the page. You get a callback when the result is return, which you can then use to populate and show the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want it in the callback for whatever ajax request you're using to get information from your server.

```
$.get("your-script.php", function(data){
    // display data here
});
```